# Setting end of char array to '\0'

Tags: c, arrays

I am having difficulty setting the last element of my array to '\0'. Can someone please guide me, I am doing this -

```
char cipher[count+1];
cipher[count+1] = '\0';
```

However this is the output i get in the debugger

[Output from degubber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhgW5.png)

Answer (score 4):

The final index of an array is one less than the total number of elements. To zero the last index here, you want:

```
char cipher[count+1];
cipher[count] = '\0';  // No +1 here
```

or just simplify to zeroing the whole thing which can avoid bugs if you fail to initialize the other elements:

```
char cipher[count+1] = {0};
```